# Why does TypeScript not pass casted object instances correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I've been working on implementing features for an Angular web app. We connect to various API endpoints, which return JSON responses. Here is an example of such a request:

```
import { RecipesResponse } from '../../models/response/recipes';

getRecipes(): Observable<RecipesResponse> {
    const url = `/recipes`;

    return this.http.request('GET', url).pipe(
    catchError(this.errorHandler.handleError)
    ) as Observable<RecipesResponse>;
}
```

The Observable 'Recipes Response' object class is defined as follows:

```
export class RecipesResponse {
    errors: string[];
    recipes: string[];

    constructor(args: any) {
        if (!args) {
            return null;
        }

        for (const field in args) {
            if (args.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                this[field] = args[field];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the requesting logic from the Angular component:

```
getTheRecipes(): void {
    this.recipeService.getRecipes().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(
        response => {
            const recipesResponse = new RecipesResponse(response);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

The difference here is `response` is exactly how the server provides the data, and `recipesResponse` formats the data according to the `RecipesResponse` class. However, **I would expect `response` to be formatted according to the `RecipesResponse` class since `getRecipes()` returns `as Observable<RecipesResponse>;`. Why does it not work this way?**

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with Angular, but isn't it a problem that you're not doing anything with recipesResponse (i.e. returning it)?

Comment: @JBC this is sample code, I removed the logic that handles `recipesResponse` since it wasn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TypeScript gets transpired into JavaScript, all typing information is lost. Typescript is very helpful during development time and will tell you if there is anything wrong, however, if the data that comes from the server does not match the expected format, it will only complain when you try to access a property that does not exist.

So whenever you receive data from the backend, it is prudent to validate it if you're not sure of the format (or if there is a possibility another type of object is returned in case of an error).